# Visual Studio or Resharper functionality for placement of using directives

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, using-directives

I like to put my using directives inside the current namespace, and not outside as VS and Resharper per default puts them.

Does anyone know of a macro/standard functionality that sorts/removes unused using directives and puts them *inside* the current namespace?

Answer (score 225, accepted):

**UPDATE - ReSharper 2016.1**: This option is now moved to *Code Editing → C# → Code Style → Add 'using' directive to the deepest scope*

Have you tried the ReSharper option:

*Languages → C# → Formatting Style → Namespace Imports → Add using directive to the deepest scope*

I'm not sure whether R#'s code cleanup will reorder the existing ones for you though.

Comment: In ReSharper 6, this options is now at `Code Editiong` -> `C#` -> `Namespace Imports` (not under Formatting Style).

Comment: _I'm not sure whether R#'s code cleanup will reorder the existing ones for you though_
 - In R# 6 it does.

Comment: If you want to automatically fix not only this rule, but a bunch of the other ones also, it's better to update your StyleCop to the version 4.7 or higher, because it includes ReSharper plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10884463/182371

Comment: In Resharper 9 this option moved to `Code Editing -> C# -> Code Style`

Comment: in resharper 10 this now doesn't work anymore (at least on my machine :-/)

Comment: In Resharper 10, it's in the same place that @JoaoMillasch mentioned. It's under the "Reference  qualification" grouping.

Comment: Does not work in R# 10 any more. There is no such an option.

Comment: in R# 10 "Reference qualification" is under C# - Formatting Style - Code Style

Answer (score 43):

In **ReSharper 2020**, go to Options and then:

> `Code Editing` → `C#` → `Syntax Style` → `Add 'using' directive to deepest scope`

[image]

Answer (score 18):

As of version 8.2, this has moved. It is now here:

Within Visual Studio
Resharper -> Options...

Then in the Options dialog
Code Editing -> C# -> Namespace Imports -> Insert using directives when necessary -> Add using directive to the deepest scope

[image]

Answer (score 16):

As of Resharper 9 this has moved into `Code Editing` => `C#` => `Code Style` => `Reference Qualification` => `Add 'using' directive to deepest scope`.

Or you can use new settings search facility and search for `deepest scope`. The exact setting will come up:

[image: Add 'using' directive to deepest scope]

Answer (score 2):

StyleCop supports ReSharper integration starting from version 4.7.

From http://stylecop.codeplex.com/:

> 4.7 is compatible with JetBrains R#5.1( 5.1.3000.12), R#6.0 (6.0.2202.688), R#6.1 (6.1.37.86), R#6.1.1 (6.1.1000.82) and R#7.0
>   (7.0.54.77)
>
> 4.7 is compatible with Visual Studio 2008, Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 11
>
> **This release includes the StyleCop ReSharper plugin** (compatible with
>   ReSharper 5.1, 6.0, 6.1, 6.1.1 and 7.0)

Answer (score 1):

I've [edited my default visual studio templates](http://www.thecodinghumanist.com/Content/HowToEditVSTemplates.aspx) to put my using directives inside the namespace.

For sorting and removing unused directives, I use [Power Commands for Visual Studio 2008](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands).

Answer (score 1):

**Update for Resharper 2020.1**: This option can now be found in *Options → Code Editing → C# → Syntax Style → Reference Qualification and 'using' Directives*

[Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxIWr.png)