# visual studio 2010 inserts using directives inside namespace

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, code-formatting, stylecop, stylecop-plus

I have exactly opposite problem to one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820795/visual-studio-or-resharper-functionality-for-placement-of-using-directives). In my case Visual Studio inserts using directives inside namespace and I want to prevent this. I did try to uncheck Resharper option:
Languages -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Namespace Imports -> Add using directive to the deepest scope
And it didn't help. Also I tried to temporary disable the Resharper. Still same issue.
Btw, I have StyleCop and StyleCop+ installed as well. Maybe it is causing the issue.
So right now when I go and Add New Item -> Class - it will create new code file with using directives inside namespace. How to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you replace your class template file with one that has one or more using directives inside the namespace declaration?  If so, you're probably seeing the result of an interesting bit of C# plugin behavior: a newly added using directive is placed after the last recognized using directly already in the file, regardless of where that is.

Comment: Where can I find the template for class file?

Comment: The default location for the class template is under `<Visual Studio root directory>\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033`.  If you do change the class template, you will likely need to force Visual Studio to refresh its template cache as described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms241279(v=vs.100).aspx.