# Set ReSharper to put the 'using' import outside the namespace

Tags: namespaces, resharper, stylecop, using-statement

I've ReSharper v9.0 installed on my VS. I also use StyleCop. I've disabled SA1200, so when I put the `using` statements outside the namespace, I don't get warned again. But when I add a reference via [alt]+[enter], which isn't available in using statements, R# put it inside the namespace. Of course, it is not consistent right, R# should place it outside the namespace.

I've tried to reset R# setting to factory default, it works as I expected. But when I apply StyleCop rules again, this problem happen again. 
How should I setup this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio or Resharper functionality for placement of using directives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820795/visual-studio-or-resharper-functionality-for-placement-of-using-directives)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Answer from another question:

> UPDATE - Resharper 9: This option is now moved to Code Editing -> C# -> Code Style
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/825256/67420

Comment: ReSharper 10: Options -> Code Editing -> C# -> Code Style -> Reference qualification : "Add 'using' directive to deepest scope"