# Reorder usings and keep them OUTSIDE of the namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, stylecop

We would like to `Reorder using statements` and keep them **outside** of the `namespace`. ReSharper puts them inside the `namespace` when reordering.

[Visual Studio or Resharper functionality for placement of using directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820795/visual-studio-or-resharper-functionality-for-placement-of-using-directives) asks how to put `usings` inside the `namespace.` That is not what we would like to do. Its answer suggest going to `ReSharper > Options > Code Editing → C# → Code Style → Add 'using' directive to the deepest scope`. Despite having un-selected that, on re-ording the `usings`, ReSharper places the usings inside the `namespace`.

[image]

How can we `Reorder using statements` and keep them outside the `namespace`?

Additional things we have tried:

Our StyleCop.Analyzers ruleset includes the following directive related rules:

```
SA1200 Using directives must be placed correctly
SA1208 System using directives must be placed before other using directives
SA1209 Using alias directives must be placed after other using directives
SA1210 Using directives must be ordered alphabetically by namespace
```

Given those rules along with the selection in Options not to "Add `usings` to the deepest scope", we receive the following warning on build:

```
SA1200 Using directive must appear within a namespace declaration.
```

How can we configure ReSharper to enforce that using directives must appear **outside** a namespace declaration?

Answer (score 7):

Add `stylecop.json` to the project with the following setting:

```
{  
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/master/StyleCop.Analyzers/StyleCop.Analyzers/Settings/stylecop.schema.json",
  "settings": {
    "orderingRules": {
      "usingDirectivesPlacement": "outsideNamespace"
    }
  }
}
```

Then, [enable the use of `stylecop.json`](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/EnableConfiguration.md) by editing the `ProjectName.csproj` file, locating the following item in the project file...

```
<None Include="stylecop.json" />
```

... and changing the definition to the following.

```
<AdditionalFiles Include="stylecop.json" />
```

Comment: Just to clarify, this is changing the settings for the StyleCopAnalyzers, which means that ReSharper isn't involved here.

Comment: @citizenmatt Oddly enough, ReSharper honors the setting. That is, when we `Reorder using` with ReSharper, it puts them outside of the namespace if and only if we've added this. Is that your experience? Or, am I missing something?

Comment: ReSharper has no knowledge of this file, so can't be honouring the setting. When you're invoking the "reorder usings", is this from the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> menu, and if so, does the item have a little Visual Studio icon next to it? I think what's happening is that you're actually invoking Visual Studio's actions from ReSharper's menus. But it's not ReSharper doing the work here.